# controlling position of pendulum with motor

Tags: dynamical-systems

There is a pendulum with a motor mounted at its point of rotation. The
motor can generate a rotational force at any time, thus changing the dynamics to $θ" = −a*sinθ − b*θ" +  u$

where $u$ is the torque generated by the motor. If we discretize the system, given current angle $θ_t$ and angular
velocity $θ'_t$, the angle and angular velocity at time $t + h$ can be calculated as
$$θ_{t+h} = θ_t + h * θ'_t$$

$$θ'_{t+h} = θ'_t + h(−asinθ_t − b *θ'_t + u)$$

Now suppose we want the pendulum to stay upward (θ = π, or 180 degree). Given measurements of the current angle $θ$ and angular
velocity $θ'$, how would you apply the motor torque $u$ to achieve this?

I know that when $θ =π $ the equilibrium point is unstable. So to make this point stable we add $u$. 
I don't know how to find the function of $u$.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a change of variables to your system $\tilde{\theta} = \theta-\pi$ so that $\tilde{\theta} = 0$ is an unstable point (if you look at the system without $u$). Then you just need to select your $u$ in such a way that the transformed system looks exactly like the old one (then $\tilde{\theta}=0$ will stable).